# Custom Transformers work individually but breaks down when combining them into one Pipeline

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn, pipeline

I need some help debugging. I am using scikit-learn to process some data and train an ML model to predict housing prices. I have come up with 2 custom transformers that takes care of unwanted features, and also combines a few features to create new features. Both custom transformers work individually when I call them but as soon as I combine them into a single pipeline to improve the workflow, I get an error. im not sure what the issue is.
for example, here is the first transformer:

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class ColumnSelector(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, columns):
        self.columns = columns

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X):
        return X[self.columns]
```

then testing it out:

```
relevant_columns = ['OverallQual','GrLivArea','GarageCars','GarageArea','YearBuilt','BsmtFinSF1','FullBath', 
                    'GarageYrBlt', 'TotalBsmtSF', '2ndFlrSF', '1stFlrSF', 'HalfBath']

cs = ColumnSelector(columns=relevant_columns)
transformed = cs.fit_transform(X_train)

transformed.head()
```

[returns this dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MwLbz.png).

similarly,

```
class CombinedAttributesAdder(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    total_bsmt_sa_ix, second_flr_ix, first_flr_ix, full_bath_ix, half_bath_ix = [
    list(transformed.columns).index(col) for col in ('TotalBsmtSF', '2ndFlrSF', '1stFlrSF', 'FullBath', 'HalfBath')]

    def __init__(self, add_total_sa=True, add_total_baths=True):
        self.add_total_sa = add_total_sa
        self.add_total_baths = add_total_baths

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):

            if self.add_total_sa and self.add_total_baths:
                total_sa = X[:, total_bsmt_sa_ix] + X[:, second_flr_ix] + X[:, first_flr_ix]
                total_bath = X[:, full_bath_ix] + X[:, half_bath_ix]/2
                return np.c_[X, total_sa, total_bath]

            elif self.add_total_sa:
                total_sa = X[:, total_bsmt_sa_ix] + X[:, second_flr_ix] + X[:, first_flr_ix]
                return np.c_[X, total_sa]

            elif self.add_total_baths:
                total_bath = X[:, full_bath_ix] + X[:, half_bath_ix]/2
                return np.c_[X, total_bath]

            else:
                pass

atr_adder = CombinedAttributesAdder()
housing_extra_attr = atr_adder.transform(transformed.values)

housing_extra_attr = pd.DataFrame(housing_extra_attr, columns=relevant_columns+['total_sa', 'total_bath'], index=transformed.index)
housing_extra_attr.head()
```

[returns this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Bwl5.png)

however, when I make a pipeline like so:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('column_selector', ColumnSelector(columns=relevant_columns)),
    ('attr adder', CombinedAttributesAdder()),
    ('scaler', StandardScaler())
])

X_train_prepd = pipeline.fit(X_train)
```

I get this error message

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-ab78197544be> in <module>
      8 ])
      9 
---> 10 X_train_prepd = pipeline.fit(X_train)

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_book\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    350             This estimator
    351         """
--> 352         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    353         with _print_elapsed_time('Pipeline',
    354                                  self._log_message(len(self.steps) - 1)):

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_book\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    315                 message_clsname='Pipeline',
    316                 message=self._log_message(step_idx),
--> 317                 **fit_params_steps[name])
    318             # Replace the transformer of the step with the fitted
    319             # transformer. This is necessary when loading the transformer

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_book\lib\site-packages\joblib\memory.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    353 
    354     def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
--> 355         return self.func(*args, **kwargs)
    356 
    357     def call_and_shelve(self, *args, **kwargs):

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_book\lib\site-packages\sklearn\pipeline.py in _fit_transform_one(transformer, X, y, weight, message_clsname, message, **fit_params)
    714     with _print_elapsed_time(message_clsname, message):
    715         if hasattr(transformer, 'fit_transform'):
--> 716             res = transformer.fit_transform(X, y, **fit_params)
    717         else:
    718             res = transformer.fit(X, y, **fit_params).transform(X)

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_book\lib\site-packages\sklearn\base.py in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    551         if y is None:
    552             # fit method of arity 1 (unsupervised transformation)
--> 553             return self.fit(X, **fit_params).transform(X)
    554         else:
    555             # fit method of arity 2 (supervised transformation)

<ipython-input-94-607115cdc09e> in transform(self, X, y)
     13 
     14             if self.add_total_sa and self.add_total_baths:
---> 15                 total_sa = X[:, total_bsmt_sa_ix] + X[:, second_flr_ix] + X[:, first_flr_ix]
     16                 total_bath = X[:, full_bath_ix] + X[:, half_bath_ix]/2
     17                 return np.c_[X, total_sa, total_bath]

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_book\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2978             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2979                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2980             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2981             if is_integer(indexer):
   2982                 indexer = [indexer]

~\Anaconda3\envs\ml_book\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 )
   2896             try:
-> 2897                 return self._engine.get_loc(key)
   2898             except KeyError:
   2899                 return self._engine.get_loc(self._maybe_cast_indexer(key))

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas\_libs\index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

TypeError: '(slice(None, None, None), 8)' is an invalid key
```

Does anyone have an idea on what could be going wrong? Im really floored here.
Thanks for the help

Comment: Can you try moving the `total_bsmt_sa_ix, second_flr_ix ...` command in your `CombinedAttributesAdder` to the `__init__` and append self to each variable?

Comment: I can try that and see if it works. However, I think I know what the issue is. The `CombinedAttributesAdder()` needs a numpy array as input for some reason, but if I convert the return from `ColumnSelector()` to give an array instead of a dataframe, then the index selection breaks down

Comment: No, pipeline can handle dataframes. No need to convert to numpy. But what's `transformed.columns`. When using individually, `transformed` exists but when in pipeline that does not

Comment: `transformed.columns` are the columns from the dataframe after it's been processed by the `ColumnSelector()`  I am using this to select the columns I want to combine in the `CombinedAttributeAdder()`. Perhaps there is a better way of doing this that I am unaware of

Comment: Oh are you asking what type of object `transform.columns` is?

Comment: No no. I know what `transformed` is. I was just telling that inside the pipeline, your `CombinedAttributesAdder` will not have knowledge about the previous step before getting the data into it. So dont use it there. Move that line into the `transform()` method with `X` in place of `transformed`

Comment: Ohh I see thank you I will try that. Now would tha line have to go in the `transform` method of the column selector?

Comment: Yes. First I was suggesting to keep it into `__init__()`, but after taking into consideration that this depends on the input from previous step, that should go to the `transform()`

Comment: Ok thank you for your help. I will try this out and report back the results.

Comment: hi @VivekKumar, I tried your suggestion but it did not work. still the same error is appearing. I tried adding it in the transform function in the `ColumnTransformer` and the `CombinedAttributeAdder` and neither worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what the problem was.
The issue was coming from how I was calling the indices of the columns in the `CombinedAttributesAdder()`. the solution was to change the calculations to the following:

```
if self.add_total_sa and self.add_total_baths:
            total_sa = X.iloc[:, total_bsmt_sa_ix] + X.iloc[:, second_flr_ix] + X.iloc[:, first_flr_ix]
            total_bath = X.iloc[:, full_bath_ix] + X.iloc[:, half_bath_ix]/2
            return np.c_[X, total_sa, total_bath]

        elif self.add_total_sa:
            total_sa = X.iloc[:, total_bsmt_sa_ix] + X.iloc[:, second_flr_ix] + X.iloc[:, first_flr_ix]
            return np.c_[X, total_sa]

        elif self.add_total_baths:
            total_bath = X.iloc[:, full_bath_ix] + X.iloc[:, half_bath_ix]/2
            return np.c_[X, total_bath]

        else:
            pass
```

all I did was add `X.iloc` in each of the calculations

Comment: I overlooked the fact that when you say its working individually, you are actually changing the data in between. Your `ColumnSelector` returns `transformed` which is a `pandas.Dataframe`. But when you pass that into `CombinedAttributesAdder`, you use `transformed.values` which is a numpy array. Tha's why you can use `X[:, ...]` on the data. Pipeline will not do any change so `X` will be a `DataFrame` which cannot be used as `X[:, ...]`.

Comment: So another workaround to this solution is that you explicitly change your X to X.values either when returning from `ColumnSelector` or before using in `CombinedAttributesAdder`

Comment: Yea. I tried to change it so that `ColumnSelector` would return `X.values` but then that would mean that the column index line we were talking about would not work because now `transformed` would be an array instead of a dataframe, and I wouldn't be able to call the `.columns` method on it after

Comment: Yes, by `"before using in CombinedAttributesAdder"`, I meant you can change that in `transform()` after using the `.columns`